# How to create a conv layer where the filter doesn't move across one dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

Put another way I want the filter to cover the image across one dimension and only move in the other direction.

If I have an input with shape (ignoring batch size and number of input channels) `(h, w)`, I want to have a filter to have shape `(x, w)` where `x<h`. Would creating a filter with shape `(x, w)` and using padding of `'VALID'` be the correct thing to do (the idea being `VALID` will force that the filter is only convolved across the image when the filter 'fits' across the image in the width dimension)?

Might there be another, better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do it that way.  Another is to use the `stride` parameter to specify the stride in each dimension.  You can set the other dimension's stride to 0.  `stride=(1, 0)` is the proper syntax, I think.

Comment: Ah yeah I wanted to ask whether stride 0 is a viable option. Although it seems to me without `'valid'`, given image with width `w` and filter with width `w`, the filter would start from the first element in the image and therefore only cover half the image (as the filter extends from the first element by `w/2` in both directions)?

Comment: That coverage depends on the padding you specify.  If you restrict this to no padding at all, then the convolution can't occur except on the midline.